# Android Kotlin: map or other equivalent of converting a List to a List of Pairs?

Tags: android, arrays, list, kotlin

Suppose I have this:

```
listOf("ball","apple","zebra","cat")
```

I want to convert this to:

```
listOf(Pair("ball","b"),Pair("apple","a"),Pair("zebra","z"),Pair("cat","c"))
```

Basically I want the `second` of the Pair to be a value computed using the array value.

I realize I can create this using some combinations of a for loop. But is there a built in way using some function similar to `map` which does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
 val mylist = listOf("ball","apple","zebra","cat")
 val pairList = mylist.map{
       Pair(it, it[0])
   }
 print(pairList)
```